# How can I display data from a subarray?

Tags: angular, typescript

Actually, I want to get data from subarray. But I dont know how to get it. Could you show me how to get data from sub array. Bellow I provide my code for your reference.

app.component.html

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Title</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let tableRow of table" (click)="open(tableRow)">
      <th scope="row">{{tableRow.id}}</th>
      <td>{{tableRow.first}}</td>
      <td>{{tableRow.last}}</td>
      <td>{{tableRow.title}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div *ngIf="bellowContent">
<p>id: {{ bellowContent.id }}</p>
<p>first: {{ bellowContent.first }}</p>
<p>last: {{ bellowContent.last }}</p>
<p>title: {{ bellowContent.title }}</p>
<p>hobbies: {{ bellowContent.hobbie || null }}</p>
<p>frequency: {{bellowContent.frequency}}
</div>
```

and bellow is my component code

app.component.ts

```ts
export class AppComponent {
  closeResult: string;
  bellowContent = [];
  table = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "first":"Robin",
    "last": "William",
    "title": "back end developer",
    "hobbies": [
      {
        "hobbie": "tv",
        "frequency": "3 hours a day"
      },
      {
        "name": "game",
        "frequency": "2 hour per day"
      }
    ]
  },{
    "id": 2,
    "first":"Mark",
    "last": "Thornton",
    "title": "front end developer",
    "hobbies": [
      {
        "name": "tv",
        "frequency": "3 hours a day"
      },
      {
        "name": "game",
        "frequency": "2 hour per day"
      }
    ]
  },{
    "id": 3,
    "first":"Tary",
    "last": "Huction",
    "title": "front end developer",
    "hobbies": [
      {
        "name": "tv",
        "frequency": "3 hours a day"
      },
      {
        "name": "game",
        "frequency": "2 hour per day"
      }
    ]
  }
]


  open(tableRow) {
      this.bellowContent = tableRow
  }
}
```

For more you can refer to [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nhoazu)
Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Maybe you can edit your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show hobbies as below.

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Title</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let tableRow of table" (click)="open(tableRow)">
      <th scope="row">{{tableRow.id}}</th>
      <td>{{tableRow.first}}</td>
      <td>{{tableRow.last}}</td>
      <td>{{tableRow.title}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div *ngIf="bellowContent">
<p>id: {{ bellowContent.id }}</p>
<p>first: {{ bellowContent.first }}</p>
<p>last: {{ bellowContent.last }}</p>
<p>title: {{ bellowContent.title }}</p>
hobbies, frequency: 
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let h of bellowContent.hobbies"> 
      {{h.name}}, {{h.frequency}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```